# How to create a two column email newsletter

Tags: outlook, html-table, html-email

I am trying to create a two column email flyer but I'm having trouble with the coding as Outlook hates CSS.

I'm using tables to keep it as simple as possible but I want two separate tables on the left and the right so I can add data into it as I wish.

I tried using `float` left and right on the two tables but Outlook ignores this style.

I know the two grey tables at the bottom are each in their own separate "holder" tables but this is so I can duplicate the grey "data" tables for when I add new articles.

```
<table class="all" width="auto" height="auto" border="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td height="504">

<table width="750" height="140" border="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="200" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">&nbsp;</td>

    <td width="345" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="152" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="45" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="200" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><font color="#111111" face="Arial Narrow" size="+2">DECEMBER NEWSLETTER</font></td>
    <td width="152" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><font size="2"><strong>#4 - <span class="orange">04.12.13</span></strong></font></td>
    <td width="45" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="750" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="75" height="50" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="600" rowspan="2" scope="row"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x200"/></td>
    <td width="75" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="75" height="81" scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
    <td scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table class="holder" width="750" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" scope="row">

    <table class="inlinetableleft" width="360">
        <tr>
          <td width="371" align="left">    

<!------------LEFT COLUMN------------------>        

<table width="360" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th height="103" colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  </table>    

<!--------------LEFT COLUMN END------------->      

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="inlinetableright" width="360">
<tr>
  <td align="left">    

<!------------RIGHT COLUMN------------------>                   

<table width="360" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="106" align="left" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>       

<!-----------RIGHT COLUMN END-------------->       

</td></tr>
</table>


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a fiddle of my newsletter so far, it's the bottom two grey tables that I want to be side by side.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtyM9/)

Comment: I've not had a problem with my widths and heights. It's just a case of getting my newsletter to work without `float`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For HTML emails, nested tables are your friend :)

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMLH5/)**

Note: the border around the table is just to show you where the tables are.

```
<table border="0" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            header content here
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="300">

            <table border="0" width="300" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td>Left Content</td>
                </tr>
            </table>



        </td>
        <td width="300">

            <table border="0" width="300" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td>Right content</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works great except that if I add more data into the left column, the right column stays vertically in the middle next to the left column. I'd like the right column to stay at the top, even if I fill the left with data.

Comment: Oh yes, you'll need `valign="top"` on the `<td>` tags then. To vertically align content to the top.

Comment: I just added `valign="top"` to both `<td>` tags but it had no effect.

Comment: It should be on the `<td>` width the width currently set at `300`, not the one inside the nested table. So `<td width="300" valign="top">` should do it. http://jsfiddle.net/fRp6X/

Comment: Thank you! I was adding `valign="top"` as an inline-css. I didn't know you could just add `valign="top"` straight to the td :)

Comment: If I use the emulator option in Chrome(38) to view it as iphone 4 (or 5,6 etc.) it does not wrap the second table to the new line... is it just me? or can I ignore this?